# Counting the number of characters, words, lines in a text file

Tags: c, file, counting

I have to check the number of words, characters, and lines in a file. I am getting the number of lines and words one more than it should actually be. What is wrong with my program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *number2;

    number2 =fopen("Part2.txt", "r");
//open the file to read

    if (number2 == NULL)
    {
        return 4;
    }

    char cha;
    int character = 0;
    int word = 0;
    int lne = 0;



    while ((cha = fgetc(number2)) != EOF)
// till end of file
    {

        //character++;
        // if (cha == '\n' || cha == '\0')
        //lne++;

        while ((cha = fgetc(number2))!= EOF)

        {
            character++;
//new characters

            if (cha == '\n' || cha == '\0')
                lne++;
// new lines


            if (cha == ' ' || cha == '\t' || cha == '\n' || cha == '\0')
                word++;
//new words--- though the professor talks about only whitespace this is proper way

        }

        if (character > 0)
        {
            word++;
            lne++;

        }
// increasing the worlds and lines for last word and printing


        printf("\n");
        printf("Total number of characters = %d\n", character);
        printf("Total number of words      = %d\n", word-1);
        printf("Total number of lines      = %d\n", lne-1);
// decreasing by 1 in word and line because there is one extra line and this runs the code perfectly

        fclose (number2);
//closing the file though professor didn't ask for smooth functioning of programms

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us a sample file along with the expected and actual results?

Comment: Huh? Why nested loops? And the number  of words is not the same as the number of white spaces, try inserting many spaces between two words in your input and see.